# How do I route all internet traffic from one Mac to another?

Tags: macos, network, vpn, proxy, internet-sharing

I think this should be possible but I'm not knowledgeable to make it work myself.

I have a MacBook that has a VPN connection and I want to be able to access this VPN connection from another MacBook.

The setup looks something like this:

```
MacBook 2 -- ethernet --> MacBook 1 <----> Wi-Fi --> Non VPN traffic (default gateway)
                                                |
                                                 --> VPN traffic (VPN gateway on ppp0 netif for some IP ranges, eg: 10.35/16 and 10.24/16)
```

Ideally, I could route all internet traffic from MacBook 2 to MacBook 1 and have MacBook 1 decide where it should go (through VPN gateway or through my normal gateway). So if I accessed `10.35.2.4` from MacBook 2, it would go to MacBook 1, through the VPN and back to MacBook 2. And if I accessed `35.3.3.3` (an IP not in the VPN traffic range) it would simply go to my default gateway and back to MacBook 1.

How would I go setting this up?

Comment: Most VPN are designed to lock out all other network sources and not funnel traffic in the manner you describe. Are you confident you can do a split tunnel VPN with your VPN provider?

Comment: Yes, split tunneling with my VPN connection has already been enabled and setup on MacBook 1. Traffic going to specific ip ranges go through VPN and the rest goes through my normal gateway.

Comment: Awesome. My answer should help get you started then! I don’t have a cookbook to do the vpn part, so feel free to edit my answer or select another that solves the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easy part is sharing internet without VPN. Let’s cover that first. Sign out of VPN and set up network sharing.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-internet-connection-mac-network-users-mchlp1540/mac

Once that’s working, you may need to ensure your VPN allows split tunneling and get into very specific configuration details to pull this off but this is a very typical software defined network configuration. Mac 1 is functioning as a router and that router has a point to point VPN tunnel to another router serving the destination network segments you defined.

Comment: So if my VPN allows split tunneling and is already setup, is Mac OS's internet sharing all I need to get this setup to work?